# Can't get cursor positon after the entry has been enabled MVVM

Tags: xamarin

If I set the entry `IsEnable = false` then after to `true` and write something, I don't get the cursor position.

Does someone have an idea about it?
Thanks a lot

**XAML**

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <view:TestViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*, Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto">
               <Grid RowDefinitions="40,40,*" ColumnDefinitions="20,*,20">
                    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                           IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                           Text="{Binding TextTest}"
                           CursorPosition="{Binding TextCursorPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Margin="0"
                           TextColor="Black">
                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                            <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="TextChanged"
                                Command="{Binding TextChangedAsyncCommand}"/>
                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                    </Entry>
                </Grid>

            <Button Grid.Row="1"
                    Command="{Binding IsAsyncCommand}"
                    Text="Enable Entry"
                    BorderWidth="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**CS**

```
public partial class TestViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public AsyncCommand<object> TextChangedAsyncCommand { get; }
    public AsyncCommand IsAsyncCommand { get; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _textTest;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _textCursorPosition;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isEnabled;


    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TextChangedAsyncCommand = new AsyncCommand<object>(TextChangedTask);
        IsAsyncCommand = new AsyncCommand(IsTextTask);
    }


    private Task TextChangedTask(object arg)
    {
        if (arg is not TextChangedEventArgs e) return Task.CompletedTask;

        var entryCursorPosition = TextCursorPosition;
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    private Task IsTextTask()
    {
        IsEnabled = true;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Xamarin but the same code works fine in MAUI.

Comment: do you think it's a bug?